# FileUpload widget in Jupyter notebook - How to access uploaded file

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

> uploader = widgets.FileUpload()

> uploader

Produces a box that you can click and upload a file (a jpg or png for example). How do I code to access this and use it in future code?

For example, if I want to print the uploaded image.

Thanks!!

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsWXc.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty general question, so I can only provide a general answer.  This would be the full uploader code to print the image properties:

```
    import ipywidgets as widgets
    
    uploader = widgets.FileUpload()
    uploader

    from PIL import Image
    
    for name, file_info in uploader.value.items():
        img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(file_info['content']))
        
    print(img)
```

From there you can pass the image to cv or other image processors as well.